# coldfusion bug in Replace function

Tags: replace, coldfusion

Here is my program:

```
<cfset test = 'a~b~~c~d~~~e'>
<cfset test2 = Replace(test, '~~','~X~','all')>
<cfoutput>  
        test  #test# 
   <br> test2 #test2# 
   <br>wanted: a~b~X~c~d~X~X~e
</cfoutput>
```

The output I got:

```
test a~b~~c~d~~~e  
test2 a~b~X~c~d~X~~e  
wanted: a~b~X~c~d~X~X~e
```

So the output of test2 is wrong This no doubt has to do with the inner workings of the Replace function, but I need it to work correctly.

Does anyone know of a workaround for this problem?

Comment: Does this `#Replace(ArrayToList(ListToArray(test, '~~', true, true), '~X~'), '~~','~X~','all')#` work for all your use cases? [Example](https://cffiddle.org/app/file?filepath=79fbaa81-df62-49cf-bf2a-f6e31d8af540/897b3615-23b4-46d3-b23d-213a221bc8e8/3e941d20-039f-4598-95d0-fd8dfa704474.cfm)

Comment: I wouldn't expect replace() to produce what you described as the desired results.  It sounds more like your requirement is to insert an "X" in between any two tildes "~~".  A regex with a non-capturing look-ahead should accomplish that https://trycf.com/gist/916579ab2dbe0d8eac229bfd45aa4c33/lucee5?theme=monokai

Comment: @rrk Yes that does work.  Would you be kind enough to explain it a little or refer me to some documentation.

Comment: @BettyMock I think the answer I added in the comments is bit of an overkill. You just need to do what @SOS suggested OR do the `Replace(test2, '~~','~X~','all')` again on `test2`. Once `~~` is replaced with `~X~` twice, all the `~~` will be removed from the string.

Comment: @rrk, your modesty might be unwarranted.  I went to your example and added an extra tilde to variable test.  `<cfset test = 'a~b~~c~d~~~~e'>`.  The result was, `dynamic wanted: a~b~X~c~d~X~X~X~e `.  @BettyMock will have to verify it, but I think you nailed it.

Comment: @rrk - Yeah, agreed a regex , or a double replace, is a clearer way to do it.  I'm not a huge of using regex's where basic string functions will do, but this seems like a good use for it. However, either would do the trick, so you should post yours as another answer, to provide an alternative approach (:

Comment: @rrk I did try a double replace and it worked for my situation.  However, I suspect it would not work if there are many tildes ~~~~~~~.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not a bug.

[Replace()](https://cfdocs.org/replace) doesn't have any special ["lookaround"](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) capability. It just walks the input string until it finds `~~`. Then jumps to the next character - **after** the matched text - and continues searching. Resulting in only two matches.

[image: How Replace searches the string]

It sounds more like the requirement is to insert an "X" in between any two tildes "~~". A regex with a non-capturing look-ahead should accomplish that.

```
 reReplace(test, '~(?=~)','~X','all')
```

*Explanation*

- `~` Find tilde
- `(?=~)` .. followed by another tilde

[Demo Example](https://trycf.com/gist/916579ab2dbe0d8eac229bfd45aa4c33/lucee5?theme=monokai)